# What to use instead of HTML data attributes when you need to recall IDs later

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel-5

So I was reading [this article](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) where it states,

> External software should not interact with it *[data attributes]*. Marking up contact details or event details using custom data attributes would be wrong...

However, I have a list of 100 or so topics as such,

```
<li class="topic" data-topic-id="1" data-original-topic-name="Interaction Design">
    <input value="Interaction Design">
    <button class="edit-topic">Edit</button>
    <button class="delete-topic">Delete</button>
</li>
```

And in my JS I just set a button listener for edit-topic and delete-topic classes, and send the relevant AJAX request with parents data-topic-id as the payload ID. Is this alright even though the user could change the ID? If not, how could I bind/set an ID to a button without the user seeing the value?

Comment: How does the user change the ID?

Comment: Developer web tools, you can just change the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an int for an id you could use a GUID then you don't need to worry about users guessing ids.

Also on server side you can check to see if the logged in user has access to that id before doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the key challenge is the user could spoof an AJAX request to replace a predictable value with another to access privileged data they shouldn't have.  If this is the case, one can replace the predictable IDs with unpredictable hashes, preferably unique for every user on every load of your web app.

In other words, something like this:

```
<li data-topic-id="1" ...
```

Becomes something like this:

```
<li data-topic-id="749943a1-bc29-40d2-ad8f-ba8843d77121" ...
```

And on the next app load, the id changes again like so:

```
<li data-topic-id="d033a221-26c9-4aac-b278-84cbf4c038c5" ...
```

One would need to correlate the hash to the meaning for each user. There are a few ways to do this.  I would consider JWTs, which are horizontally scalable and can discourage casual attackers (the JWTs can contain the index number therefore does not require a database lookup). Another approach is to use and set a new decrypt key or a serialized lookup map set on every application load as illustrated below:

```
# Serialized lookup-map per user in session table
| session_id | user_id | lookup_map_str
| 123456     | fred    | { '749943a1...' : 1, ... }

# Decryption key
| session_id | user_id | decrypt_key
| 123456     | fred    | xyzpdq
```

If this is generally available information, all this may be overkill. How, exactly, do you see your app being compromised currently by using these ID's? If, for example, as user is not authorized to get category '2', that should handled in the AJAX request, so even if the user hand-crafts an AJAX call, the auth system would deny that request.

In general, you should trust nothing coming from the client without proper credentials, because your client can be spoofed.

Let me know if that helps.

ps. Since you're making an AJAX call, the chances you are already looking up a session table row is highly likely, and in any event is probably negligible overhead. For those reasons I'd probably start with the serialized lookup map first and then adjust as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is pretty much an alright use case. And one way or the other - you'll need server-side validation to make sure users aren't editing what they aren't supposed to edit.